# Передать preventDefault другому событию

Tags: javascript, jquery, события

При возникновении одного события, триггерится другое, причём по имени. В некоторых случаях обработчик того события может вызвать `preventDefault`. Как проверить, был ли он вызван и передать это состояние первому событию?

https://jsfiddle.net/edgv8qur/1/

```js
$("button").click(function (event) {
  $("body").trigger("some-custom-event");

  // Если кастомное событие было отменено, отменить и это
  if (true) { // Как проверить?
    event.preventDefault();
  }
})

$("body").on("some-custom-event", function (event) {
  if (Math.random() > .5) {
    console.log("prevent");
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    console.log("allow");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Test</button>
```

PS: [Этот же вопрос по-английски.](//stackoverflow.com/q/36162098/4928642)

Comment: Что мешает создать внешнюю переменную и хранить состояние в ней?

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36162098/4928642

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На основе [ответа](//stackoverflow.com/a/36162355/4928642) от [Mustafa Shujaie](//stackoverflow.com/users/2309944/mustafa-shujaie):

```js
$("button").click(function (event) {
  var e = $.Event("some-custom-event");
  $("body").trigger(e);

  // Если кастомное событие было отменено, отменить и это
  if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("prevented!");
  }
})

$("body").on("some-custom-event", function (event) {
  if (Math.random() > .5) {
    console.log("prevent");
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    console.log("allow");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл такой способ, но что-то он мне не нравится:

```js
$("button").click(function (event) {
  $("body")
    .one("some-custom-event", function (e) {
      if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("prevented!")
      }
    })
    .trigger("some-custom-event");
})

$("body").on("some-custom-event", function (event) {
  if (Math.random() > .5) {
    console.log("prevent");
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    console.log("allow");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Test</button>
```